# Setting the DataContext for a ContextMenu from a ListView's ItemContainer?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, binding

I am using the mvvm pattern and I am having a hard time figuring out how to set the DataContext on a ContextMenu from inside a ListView’s ItemContainerStyle.

I also do not understand why the ListView.ContextMenu and the ListView’s GridView.ColumnHeaderContextMenu can see the properties and commands from my view model, but the ContextMenu inside the ListView.ItemContainerStyle cannot.

**Error**

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'AddMenuItem' property not found on 'object' ''Currency' (HashCode=43406546)'. BindingExpression:Path=AddMenuItem; DataItem='Currency' (HashCode=43406546); target element is 'ContextMenu' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

**View**

```
<!-- Removed styles for clarity. -->
<UserControl>

<!-- Add ElementSpy to the UserControl’s rsources -->
<UserControl.Resources>
    <framework:ElementSpy x:Key="spy" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Currency}">

    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <!-- 'AddMenuItem' property not found on 'object' 'Currency' -->
                    <!-- ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding AddMenuItem}" / -->

                    <!-- Use the ElementSpy resource -->
                    <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource spy}, Path=Element.DataContext.AddMenuItem}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListView.ContextMenu>
        <!-- Works -->
        <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding EditMenuItem}" />
    </ListView.ContextMenu>

    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.ColumnHeaderContextMenu>
                <!-- Works -->
                <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding SortMenuItem}" />
            </GridView.ColumnHeaderContextMenu>

            <GridViewColumn Header="Code"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Code}" />

            <GridViewColumn Header="Description"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Description}" />

            <GridViewColumn Header="Exchange Rate"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ExchangeRate}" />
        </GridView>

    </ListView.View>

</ListView>
</UserControl>
```

**Code Behind**

```
[Export(ViewNames.CurrencyMasterView, typeof(IMasterView))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public partial class CurrencyMasterView
    : UserControl, IMasterView
{
    public CurrencyMasterView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [Import]
    private MasterViewModel ViewModel
    {
        set
        {
            this.DataContext = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
[Export(typeof(MasterViewModel))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class MasterViewModel
    : ViewModelBase
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MasterViewModel(IGeneralController generalController, IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Currency> Currency
    {
        get
        {
            return this.currency;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this.currency != value)
            {
                this.currency = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Currency);
            }
        }
    }

    public List<MenuItemMvvm> SortMenuItem
    {
        get
        {
            return this.CreateSortMenuItem();
        }
    }

    public List<MenuItemMvvm> EditMenuItem
    {
        get
        {
            return this.CreateEditMenuItem();
        }
    }

    public List<MenuItemMvvm> AddMenuItem
    {
        get
        {
            return this.CreateAddMenuItem();
        }
    }

    private List<MenuItemMvvm> CreateEditMenuItem()
    {
        var menu = new List<MenuItemMvvm>();

        menu.Add(new MenuItemMvvm("_Edit")
        {
            Command = this.EditCommand,
            Icon = new Image
            {
                Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/POS.Modules.Core;component/Resources/Images/16X16/Edit.png"))
            }
        });

        menu.Add(new MenuItemMvvm("_Duplicate")
        {
            Command = this.DuplicateCommand,
            Icon = new Image
            {
                Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/POS.Modules.Core;component/Resources/Images/16X16/Copy.png"))
            }
        });

        menu.Add(new MenuItemMvvm("_Delete")
        {
            Command = this.DeleteCommand,
            Icon = new Image
            {
                Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/POS.Modules.Core;component/Resources/Images/16X16/Delete.png"))
            }
        });


        return menu;
    }

    // Other methods removed for clarity
}
```

Comment: kevin: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504533 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306386 - you can bind via ContextMenu.PlacementTarget.

Answer (score 2):

This question helped me figure it out.
[WPF MenuItem.Command binding to ElementName results to System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617122/wpf-menuitem-command-binding-to-elementname-results-to-system-windows-data-error)

I updated the source for anyone else that is having this issue.

For quick reference this is what I did.

Add Josh Smith's ElementSpy class. [Enable ElementName Bindings with ElementSpy](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/07/22/enable-elementname-bindings-with-elementspy/)

Add ElementSpy to the UserControl’s rsources.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <framework:ElementSpy x:Key="spy" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then bind to the resource and use the Element property to bind to the DataContext and the property that you choose.

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource spy}, Path=Element.DataContext.AddMenuItem}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use RelativeSource and PlacementTarget in your binding. i use the following xaml to add a contextmenu to set visibility of datagrid columns.

```
  <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Spalten ein-/ausblenden">                           
                        <StackPanel>
                            <ItemsControl 
                            ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget.Columns, Mode=OneWay}"
                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Visibility4DataGridColumns}"
                            ></ItemsControl>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```